# Monitoring wso2 carbon using Appdynamics

Tags: java, instrumentation, wso2, appdynamics

HI I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on using  Appdynamics  to monitor WSO2.

Out of the box appdynamics detects the servlet request coming in and that it gets written to the database, but beyond that it loses track of the transaction.

```
Filter - CharacterSetFilter:doFilter (method time = 12 ms, total time = 40896 ms)
 HTTPServlet:service:722 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 40884 ms)
  HTTPServlet:service:722 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 40884 ms)
   HTTPServlet:service:641 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 40884 ms)
    Servlet - CarbonServlet:doPost:231 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 40884 ms)
     Axis2 Webservice Servlet:doPost:146 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 40884 ms)
      Web Service - org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver:receive:110 (method time = 453 ms, total time = 40884 ms)
       JDBC(96 ms): [0]
       JDBC(195 ms): [1]
       JDBC(44 ms): [2]

       java.lang.Object:wait (method time = 40431 ms, total time = 40431 ms)
```

so if anyone could give some help as to what other classes I should instrument, It would be a real help.

thanks

Sunil Vanmullem

Answer (score 0):

I've instrumented  org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.handleJobDetails and it is showing me transactions going through Carbon out to the backends.